# Is there any function in javascript, to detect a change in document?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I have an HTML page, which contains many select boxes, to beautify those boxes I have used "select2", What I have done is:

```
$(document).ready(function() { $("select").select2(); });
```

This makes all of the select boxes to get transform like "select2".
But now I am generating the tables on a button click(after the document is ready), therefore the newly generated select boxes doesn't looks like "select2", Please help me if there is any function that detects the change in document?
Something like:

```
$(document).change(function() { $("select").select2(); });
```

Comment: Just call `.select2()` again (on the new elements) after you created the table?

Comment: @FelixKling: That's not My scenario. :(

Comment: The question is exactly what you are asking about. Changes to the DOM are made (doesn't matter how) and how can a plugin be applied to the new elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
function checkDocumentChange() {
  // Run a simple task to check whether any new "selects" were added
  var old_value = checkDocumentChange.num_selects || 0;
  var new_value = $("select").length;

  if (old_value != new_value) {
    $("select:not(.already_done)").select2();
  }

  checkDocumentChange.num_selects = new_value;
  setTimeout(checkDocumentChange, 100);
}
```

DOM events are not recommended to use since those are [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMNodeInserted).

Better approach would be, of course, to call `.select2()` right after you insert `select` into DOM. So that you will not have to delegate this to some checker or event.

Comment: There is **zero** reason to re-query the DOM 10 times a second.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I never really had to use it myself, but other approaches for this question will either require deprecated events or extending the logic of other code (I've put that into my updated answer).

Comment: @ mishik: No, they don't. See my answer, which has two suggestions other than "deprecated events or extending the logic of other code". Hint: The `NodeList` you get from `getElementsByTagName` is **live**, whereas jQuery matched sets are not.

Answer (score 2):

In at least [some browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver) (not any current version of IE, though), you *can* do this, via a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) (this is the new DOM4 thing, not the old DOM3 mutation events, which you want to stay away from).

But I don't recommend it, just call `select2` again after your code that appends the new selects.

Another option is to use a timer: Get a `NodeList` of all `select` elements on the page:

```
var allSelects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
```

...and poll checking its length (`NodeList`s are **live**, you don't have to re-query):

```
var lastLength = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    if (allSelects.length !== lastLength) {
        lastLength = allSelects.length;
        // Hook up the new ones here
    }
}, 1000); // 1000ms = 1 second
```

You could put a class on them to keep track of which ones are already done (if `select2` doesn't already do that).

But again, you have code adding `select` elements, just re-trigger there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument`

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument', function() {

}
```

Or [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/MutationObserver)

Answer (score 0):

use this id or class

in this code

```
var id = document.getelementbyid("id for select 1 or 2");

//here  the code
```

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question.